# La consola se congela en la entrada desde teclado usando getch()

Tags: c

por qué no me funciona este codigo ?, no le veo donde pueda estar la falla, se que la libreria conio no es estandar, pero de todos modos deberia funcionar...

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <conio.h>   
int main()
{   
    char password[10];
    char c;
    int i=0;
    c=getch();
    while( (c=getch()) != '\n')
    {
        password[i] = c;
        printf("*");
        i++;
    }
    password[i] = c;

    return 0;
}
```

el error es que despues de que ingreso el enter sigue pidiendo caracteres y luego se cuelga...

Comment: No es esa diagonal antes del while? De todas formas pon el error que te sale.

Comment: ah no xd esa diagonal se me paso solamente, el error es que despues de que ingreso el enter sigue pidiendo caracteres y luego se cuelga...

Comment: Que es lo que exactamente quieres lograr?... de partida no te va a servir porque no has declarado <stdio.h> ...

Comment: El error es **siempre**, o **solo cuando introduces mas de 10 caracteres** ? ¿ Pulsas alguna tecla **no imprimible** (cursores) durante el proceso ?

Comment: la stdio.h si la inclui solo que aqui s eme paso. siempre da error, apreto enter y sigue pidiendo caracteres

Answer (score -1):

Asumo que quieres hacer un algoritmo de password

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char password[10];
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        password[i]=getch();
        if (password[i]== char(13))
        {
            password[i]='\0';
            break;
        }
        printf("*");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Asi debe de funcionarte Emily

Comment: ¿Y no sería mejor, por legibilidad, poner `'\r'` en vez de `char(13)`? Y otra cosa.. eso de `password[i]='\0'` no lo termino de ver claro. Se supone que al que programe esto le gustaría encontrarse en la variable `password` la contraseña que ha introducido el usuario.

Comment: @Malthael, gracias si entiendo esa manera, solo lo que yo quiero saber e sporque de la forma que lo publico yo no funciona, siendo que deberia hacerlo, eferion el '\0' es para el fin de cadena, siempre hay que incluirlo tengo entendido

Comment: Hola @EmiliOrtega, pues no funciona porque no estas controlando el ingreso de la cadena si te das cuenta, el bucle solo se detiene hasta que presionas enter y seguira pidiendo y pidiendo datos, a consejo personal cuando trabajes con cadenas usa bucles for, que son mas comodos en estos casos, en el algoritmo que te enseñe seria mi manera de arreglar el problema, aunque le faltaria el control de retroceso (osea borrar un caracter)

Comment: @Eferion, sobre tu primer punto es mi manera de programar (te ayuda a memorizar el codigo ascii pero entiendo que la legibilidad tmb es importante), sobre password[i]='\0' es para concluir el ingreso de la cadena tras leer el enter, sino no se cierra la cadena por asi decirlo, la cadena se registra normalmente, sencillamente la condicion que ves es para cerrar la cadena

Comment: Tienes toda la razón sobre lo del `\0`. Lo vi con el móvil y se ve que no me fijé del todo. Lo del carácter ASCII... Los programas te obligan a tener mil cosas en mente y si puedes librarte de alguna tanto mejor.